# FullCalender 5 Unable to render dynamic events & resources

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to render events and resources which are stored in a database. I can get the calendar to render with predefined data for events and resources, however when I push data into the array's, the new objects do not appear when the calendar is rendered.

This is the JS code I am using to obtain the data and render the calendar;

```
    function GetCalenderDetails() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myapiendpoint',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $.each(response.bookedServices, function (i, v) {
                    services.push({
                        id: v.id,
                        title: v.title
                    });
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(services));
                $.each(response.userBookings, function (i, v) {
                    bookings.push({
                        id: v.id,
                        resourceId: v.resourceId,
                        title: v.title,
                        start: v.start,
                        allDay: v.allDayFlag
                    });
                });
                console.log(JSON.stringify(bookings));
                calendar.render();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }

    var bookings = new Array({ id: '1', resourceId: 'a', title: 'Meeting', start: '2021-03-14', allDay: true });
    var services = new Array({ id: 'a', title: 'Room A' });

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Resources',
        resources: services,
        events: bookings
    });

    GetCalenderDetails();
```

The following is the console output of the 'services' and 'bookings' variables after the GetCalenderDetails function is executed;

*Resources Output*

```
[{"id":"a","title":"Room A"},{"id":"b","title":"Room B"}]
```

*Events Output*

```
[{"id":"1","resourceId":"a","title":"Meeting","start":"2021-03-14","allDay":true}, 
{"id":"2","resourceId":"b","title":"Meeting B","start":"2021-03-15","allDay":true}]
```

The first resource and event will render, however the second item which is pushed into the array from the GetCalenderDetails function do not render.

I am  probably missing something very obvious, but I am not seeing it, so another set of eyes might help :)

Comment: Hint: Ajax calls are asynchronous. By the time you've fetched the data from Ajax, the bookings data has already been passed to fullCalendar and it's too late

Comment: See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function for a better way to structure your code

Comment: @ADyson your hint and reference to the events function was perfect, all that was needed was that extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by ADyson's comments, here is the solution to my problem just in case anyone else ends up in the same position;

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next,today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        editable: true,
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Booked Services',
        resources: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myapiendpoint',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    var resources = [];
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.status == true) {
                        $.each(response.bookedServices, function (i, v) {
                            resources.push({
                                id: v.id,
                                title: v.title
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        //Do something
                    }
                    return successCallback(resources);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        },
        events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myapiendpoint',
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    var events = [];
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.status == true) {
                        $.each(response.userBookings, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                id: v.id,
                                title: v.title,
                                start: v.start,
                                allDay: v.allDayFlag
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                         //Do something
                    }
                    return successCallback(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    calendar.render();
```